# Domain Change on SQL 2008 Report Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Our company is acquired by another one so I need to do the account migration of SQL 2008 Report Manager. For example, from **CompanyA\UserID** to **CompanyB\userID**. I did lots of searching about this, and cannot get any luck. Is there anyone can suggest me a helpful website or teach me how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "account migration"? Where are you trying to change the user accounts? Report subscriptions? The reporting services service itself?